# Azure SQL Server data center speed

Tags: azure

I have set up an Azure web site using an Azure SQL Server database.  These are placed in different locations (by accident).  The web site in Northern Europe and the SQL Server database in South Central US.

Assume I instead have the SQL Server database in Northern Europe, so that it is in the same location as the web site, would it be any faster retrieving data?  If so, by how much?  Assume I have a very inefficient query loading too much data that currently takes 15 seconds.

Please ignore the possibility of improving the query.  I am just interested in if anyone have any statistics on any speed improvements on moving where the SQL Server data centers are located related to the web site.

Comment: There's no way to answer this - you need to benchmark. It's a certainty that bandwidth between your web app and your SQL Database will be faster within the same region, since there's no dependency on any inter-region connectivity. But there's no "by how much" to share. There's no way to know what route is taken between regions, nor what speeds that traffic will be.

Comment: David is right but there's one metric that is easy to find: the ping latency between your location and the Azure data centres using http://www.azurespeed.com/

Answer (score 1):

> Assume I have a very inefficient query loading too much data that currently takes 15 seconds.

Now it will take 15.3 seconds (15 seconds + 300ms 3-way TCP handshake across the ocean).

Consider having to do 10000 queries over let's say one hour - you pay the latency penalty **FOR EACH OF THOSE QUERIES**.

In essence, move your database in the same Azure Region as your application, or vice-versa.